# Destroy user session stored in database on window close

Tags: java, database, session, web-applications

In our JAVA web application we maintain users' session in a database table `active_sessions`. And we do not allow multiple sessions per user. what it means is, if you are already logged in with a particular user account, you cannot open a new session with the same account. In case somebody does, we display error 'User already has an active session'. When user clicks on `Logout` his entry from table `active_sessions` is removed. But in case where user closes the window without logging out his entry remains in the table `active_sessions`. So any attempt to login in future results in an error 'User already has an active session'. Any tips on how to destroy user session in database in case he closes the browser window without logging out.

Edit: After reading all the posts it seems there is no clean way to restrict single session per user.

Comment: That's so dangerous!

Comment: Agree with @almasshaikh. Sessions should be automatically closed on timeout (regardless of the way the user exits the webapp). If user has not been active for a period of time, kill their session. That would allow a user to log back in again. EDIT: Alternative method, next login attempt automatically invalidates the first session, kicking that session out.

Comment: What's wrong with having multiple simultaneous 'sessions'? Is that a limitation of your web app design or a licensing/right issue? I would personally loathe any web app that restricts my freedom.

Answer (score 2):

Use the '[onbeforeonload](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm)' JavaScript event which can perform an AJAX call to your server to delete the entry. This event will however be executed each time the page is unloaded so if you don't have a SPA then you'll need to ignore the event for href and such.

Agree with Almas however that your approach is dangerous in the sense that it is not possible to enforce this 100%. E.g. if the user kills the browser process then even this JS event would not be published.
Furthermore, a user can simply use another browser to bypass your 'protection'.

Comment: Dangerous recommendation! What if, as an attacker, I see the JS that can cause session termination, and randomly terminate user sessions for other users?

Comment: @Dave, read the OP's question; this would not terminate the session but simply remove it from the DB + obviously you would not pass the sessionId in the AJAX call!

Comment: I read the question, and I presume that a deleted record from 'active_sessions' table would effectively kill the session within the rest of the webapp (otherwise, why not just leave Tomcat etc to do session management?). Can you guarantee that the entire network path is secure? If not, an attacker may be able to see sessionId's and perform the required calls to kick an active user out. Session management on client side is virtually always a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, that do solve the problem. But that means adding that script on each page ???

Comment: As long as his session is active in database, he cannot login from another browser. So multiple session check cannot be bypassed.

Comment: No, put this script in an external JS file and just import it in every page. Don't you use some templating so that you can add it to a common header or such?

Comment: @Meena; different browser => different session => different sessionId so yes, this would bypass the check.

Comment: `different browser => different session => different sessionId` how can this bypass a database based check ??

Comment: I was assuming that with sessions here you meant http sessions but when I reread your post then maybe I got this wrong. If you are not tracking http session id's but f.i. user id's then indeed, there is not issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the server side users HTTP session is normally invalided after a certain period of idle time. You can implement http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html and register it in web.xml to receive notifications about session create/destroy etc. In your listener implementation you could delete the table entry on session destroy event.

Comment: If the OP can live with it then this is certainly the way to go.

Comment: how about in case of closing browser tab. His session won't be invalidated instantly. But after a certain period of idle time. So if somebody else open a new tab within session `time-out` time he will be able to continue user's session. My main concern with this approach is that notification from `HttpSessionListener` won't be instantaneous in case of browser tab. So there is a chance of user account being compromised.

Answer (score 0):

The basic thing about HTTP is that it is request/response protocol.
i.e. Things are changed/accessed only by making a request to the server. This 'limitation' makes your requirement interesting. There can be two workarounds for this:-

1. Poll the server at a repeated interval through an AJAX call. As long as you application keeps getting the polling AJAX request you can assume that the window is open.
2. Use javascript (window.onunload ) to fire an event to destroy user session when the browser is closed.

[Using onuload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp)